# Building a Target inside a solution using MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I have a solution with two default projects inside (VisualBasic console applications):

```
Solution1\
          Solution1.sln
          ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.vbproj
          ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.vbproj
```

I have added a custom target to ConsoleApplication1:

```
  ...
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />

  <Target Name="HelloWorld">
    <Message Text="Hello Build!"></Message>
  </Target>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
  ...
</Project>
```

I would like to set up a script to execute a normal build on both projects, then call my custom target.

According to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171486.aspx, I should be able to call the specific target with the following command (ignoring the initial build of the projects for now):

```
msbuild C:\Path\To\Solution1\Solution1.sln /t:ConsoleApplication1:HelloWorld
```

Instead, I get the following error message:

error MSB4057: The target "ConsoleApplication1:HelloWorld" does not exist in the project. [E:\Path\To\Solution1\Solution1.sln]

I presume I have the syntax incorrect, what would the correct syntax be to accomplish this?

The following commands work as expected:

```
msbuild C:\Path\To\Solution1\Solution1.sln
msbuild C:\Path\To\Solution1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.vbproj /t:HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just adding your custom target action to the AfterBuild target in the desired msbuild proj file?  It's a different approach, but would eliminate the need for the explicit invocation of the custom target and still be project file specific.

Comment: It's definitely a valid workaround which I'll take (or rewrite the .sln.metaproj as a .proj) if I can't find a timely reason why the posted snippet isn't working.